# How to create a WriteStream with limit of written bytes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to implement write stream to file with fixed limit 50Mb. How to create WriteStream with that limit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I propose to count the bytes you are writing to the stream and stop writing if you have reached the limit. If you are going to pipe data from a read stream into the write stream, use the read streams 'data' event to count the bytes piped into the read stream.